# question about asynchronous operations

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am new to programming and would like to clarify some things about this and would greatly appreciate it if you who are more experienced could help me.

I'm currently programming windows forms and I am finding it very difficult to call methods asynchronously, since I'm currently using the background worker component to do this, and it makes the code very messy, since the same background worker is performing different functions that I am comparing via a switch, is there any recommendation for that? I am studying parallelism. net 4.0 but I do not think about it a good material, I use the Thread class to perform these tasks? What is the keyword async?

I appreciate any help and if you can thank any material for study that can be offered.

Sorry for my English ...

Comment: For a reasonably gentle introduction to the new async feature, see my series of 14 articles on the subject. Start from the bottom. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/async/. Also, MSDN magazine will be running some beginner-intermediate-advanced articles on this topic next month.

Comment: wy my visual studio does not recognize the word async?

Comment: @fernando Because the `async` keyword is not a part of the current version of C#. It's a feature that will be in the next version of C#.

Comment: @fernando: There is a community preview of the async feature at msdn.com/async. You can download it and give it a try; if you have feedback or suggestions or questions, post them on the async forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/threads

Comment: Eric - you should make the first comment an answer